# How to erase the key on next url when I use history.push onKeyDown?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, web-frontend

I wanna change the URL with "history.push".

but there's an input on:

```
("/main")
```

but I don't wanna put the key on "MainPage" from `Screen`.

How should I do?

```
class Screen extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.div.focus();
  }

  handleKeyDown = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      this.props.history.push("/main");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={ref => (this.div = ref)}
        tabIndex="0"
        onKeyDown={e => this.handleKeyDown(e)}
      >
        <Image />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(Screen);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can pass an object to `push()` instead.

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/main'
})
```

I didn't test. But if this doesn't work, try add the `search` argument:

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/main',
  search: ''
})
```

Doc: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#navigation